# TYPO3 a few questions about felogin

Tags: php, redirect, typo3, felogin

i would like to redirect to a page outside from the typo3. is this possible because i don´t find a input form to do that?

I have an external PHP application. This application may only be called after a successful login. Is it possible to bind the login data from felogin to a session that I can use in my PHP application? I need the login information in my PHP application. I would like to use the felogin logout mechanism in my external PHP application. Is that possible?

Regards
MS-Tech

Answer (score 0):

Not by default.

The easiest way I can think of, if the external PHP application runs on the same domain, is to alter the PHP application to read the TYPO3 frontend user cookie (fe_typo_user) and get session (fe_sessions table) and frontend user (fe_users table) data from the database.

The cleanest way I can think of is to rewrite the external PHP application as a TYPO3 extension, but I'm assuming this would be too much work.

As for the log out, you can link to the TYPO3 login page and add ?logintype=logout to the URL.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer. How can i redirect to a external Page? Have you done that before? The externa PHP application runs on the same domain. Hmm... read the TYPO3-frontend user cookie? How can i do that? With $_COOKIE["your cookie name"];? Before i can read the cookie i need a redirection to another PHP-Page. In this PHP page, I want to link between a TYPO3 user and a user of my external PHP application. To write a TYPO3 extension is to much work. Greetings

Comment: Redirecting to an external URL after login in TYPO3 can be done by making a page of the type "External URL" that links to that page and selecting this page in the login form configuration.

You can read the cookie using $_COOKIE['fe_typo_user']. This contains the session id you can use to select the data from the fe_sessions table.

Comment: OK. Thanks I got it :).